# How do you prove this trigonometric identity $2\cos^2x+\frac{1}{2}\sin^22x=\cos^4x+\sin^4x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Q: prove $2\cos^22x+\frac{1}{2}\sin^22x=\cos^4x+\sin^4x$

I think you should be able to solve with the double angle and pythagorus trigonometric equations but every time i do it, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? When I put $x=0$ I get $2=1$.

Comment: To reduce RHS, try $\cos^4{x}+\sin^4{x} = \cos^4{x}+\sin^4{x} + 2\cos^2 x \sin^2 x - 2\cos^2 x\sin^2 x$

Answer (score 1):

As the identity is indeed not an identity, let us solve the equation instead.

With obvious shorthands, we can rewrite

$$2c^2+2c^2s^2=c^4+s^4$$ or

$$2c^2+2c^2(1-c^2)=c^4+(1-c^2)^2,$$

$$4c^4-6c^2+1=0.$$

Solving this biquadratic equation, we get

$$\cos x=c=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3\pm\sqrt5}}2,$$ where the two solutions with a plus sign under the radical must be rejected.